# Importing XML to MS Access: Non standard xml?

Tags: xml, ms-access, import

I am trying to import an XML file, sourced from: https://www.dsireusa.org/resources/database-archives/ into MS Access.

I have done simple imports CSV imports previously. Upon attempting to import the XML, the import fails completely.

Snooping around, I found that the XML is formatted differently than XMLs I am able to upload successfully.
To my understanding, a standard XML looks like this:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

The XML file I have, looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<tables>
<table name="program">
    <row index="0">
        <column name="id"><![CDATA[1]]></column>
        <column name="state_id"><![CDATA[39]]></column>
        <column name="is_entire_state"><![CDATA[1]]></column>
        <column name="implementing_sector_id"><![CDATA[1]]></column>
        <column name="program_category_id"><![CDATA[2]]></column>
        <column name="program_type_id"><![CDATA[44]]></column>
        <column name="created_by_user_id"><![CDATA[534]]></column>
        <column name="code"><![CDATA[ND02R]]></column>
        <column name="name"><![CDATA[Solar Easements]]></column>
        <column name="updated_ts"><![CDATA[2017-08-10 15:14:19]]></column>
        <column name="created_ts"><![CDATA[2000-01-01 00:00:00]]></column>
        <column name="published"><![CDATA[1]]></column>
        <column name="websiteurl"><![CDATA[]]></column>
        <column name="administrator"><![CDATA[]]></column>
        <column name="fundingsource"><![CDATA[]]></column>
        <column name="budget"><![CDATA[]]></column>
        <column name="start_date"><![CDATA[]]></column>
        <column name="start_date_text"><![CDATA[]]></column>
        <column name="end_date"><![CDATA[]]></column>
        <column name="end_date_text"><![CDATA[]]></column>
        <column name="summary"><![CDATA[<p>&#10;&#9;North Dakota's solar easement law is similar to those established by many other states. The law allows a property owner to obtain a solar easement from another property owner for the purpose of ensuring adequate exposure of a solar energy system to sunlight. A solar easement must include:</p>&#10;<ul>&#10;&#9;<li>&#10;&#9;&#9;The vertical and horizontal angles, expressed in degrees, at which the solar easement extends over the real property subject to the solar easement;</li>&#10;&#9;<li>&#10;&#9;&#9;Any terms, conditions, or both under which the solar easement is granted or will be terminated; and</li>&#10;&#9;<li>&#10;&#9;&#9;Any provisions for compensation of the owner of the property benefiting from the solar easement in the event of interference with the enjoyment of the solar easement or compensation of the owner of the property subject to the solar easement for maintaining the solar easement.</li>&#10;</ul>&#10;<p>&#10;&#9;Solar easements must be created in writing and are subject to the same conveyancing and instrument recording requirements as other easements.</p>]]></column>
        <column name="additional_technologies"><![CDATA[]]></column>
        <column name="fromSir"><![CDATA[0]]></column>
    </row>
```

From what it seems to me, Access obviously doesn't recognize the formatting of this XML. Is there any easy way I could convince access to eat the broccoli I'm trying to feed it and not be a brat?

I can provide error reports from access if necessary, but considering the entire import fails, it seems to me access is not recognizing the formatting at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML documents. Specifically, migrate `@name` attributes to node names for proper import into MS Access tables. Then use a language like VBA to access Access methods: [TransformXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.transformxml) and [ImportXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.importxml).

**XSLT** *(save as an .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
     <xsl:element name="{@name}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="column">
     <xsl:element name="{@name}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHm)</kbd>

**VBA**

```vb
Public Sub import_dsireusa_xml()

    ' TRANSFORM RAW XML
    Application.TransformXML "C:\Path\To\Raw\Output.xml", _
                             "C:\Path\To\XSLT\Transform.xsl", _
                             "C:\Path\To\Final\Output.xml"

    ' RAW XML EXPORT
    Application.ImportXML "C:\Path\To\Final\Output.xml", acStructureAndData

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The same web site, from the URL you provided, has *.zip files with the *.csv files. The *.csv files have the same content as XML files. So  you can easily download *.zip files, unzip them, and load *.csv files into MS Access.

Comment: The Zip files contain only a partial database. I looked through the data. I would not waste your time without having done my due diligence. Besides, the fact that the database is 84 mb and the zip file extracts to around 28 mb should speak for itself.There is only so much bloating XML overhead can achieve